# react-select custom menu option but normal selected option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using `formatOptionLabel` to customize the options but once selected I just want `value` of option to be displayed. Seems like formatting get applied to both suggested options and selected options( or use a different formatting for the selected option). Is there a way to change this.

eg [live](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reactselect-formatoptionlabel-bde1q)